# MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP - can't access website

Tags: vba, xmlhttprequest

For instance, `kat.cr` is one of the few websites I cannot access. 
In the response, I get 2 symbols instead of the actual webpage:

[image: StrangeSymbol]

Here's the VBA code I'm using:

```
url = "https://kat.cr"
Set xmlHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
xmlHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
xmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8"
xmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
xmlHTTP.Send

Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
response = xmlHTTP.responseText
```

Is the website actually denying me access or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please fix your tag's it's either one or the other (**vb.net** or **vba**)...

Comment: All you want to get is the webpage correct?

Comment: correct, all I need is the html text of the webpage.

Comment: 436f6465786572 - fixed it, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Use `CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CreateObject("MSXML.XMLHTTP")` for client applications. `ServerXMLHttp` is meant for server applications. See [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/290761) for more information on the two.

```
Set xmlHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
xmlHTTP.Open "GET", "https://kat.cr", False
xmlHTTP.Send
Debug.Print xmlHTTP.responseText
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. I understand now why I couldn't get access. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The website is not denying you access, it's your code I am afraid. Below is a quick example to get the `HTML` you want from the page you visit.

Note: This was just a quick type-o, but to help get you in the right direction.

```
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument

Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = False
ie.navigate "https://kat.cr"

Set html = ie.document
'this is the inner html  -html.DocumentElement.innerHTML
Set ie = Nothing
```

**Edit - This might be a better solution for you**

```
Set xmlHTTP = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
xmlHTTP.Open "GET", "https://kat.cr", False
xmlHTTP.send 

Dim doc As Object
Set doc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
doc.body.innerHTML = xmlHTTP.responseText
debug.print doc.body.innerHTML
```

Comment: Isn't IE slower than xmlhttp request? I've been trying to stay of off IE for that reason.

Comment: It can be, but not that big of a difference. Many things can contribute to network differences, not just how your getting what you need...

Comment: That seems to be in the right track, I think you are working with a different version/type of VB because with both codes I get user defined type errors. But I got what you mean and indeed that got me on the right track. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome, have not worked with `vba` for a little while, I may be a little rusty :)

Comment: You did great! I'm going to have to choose bonds answer as the accepted answer, but still thanks allot for your help!

Comment: If it didn't I would remove it, that is why I am asking.

Comment: It did, that is odd. It seem's to work on my end. Thank you!

Comment: "Dim Document As HTMLDocument" in this line.

Comment: No not the first part the second section I provided :) Nevermind, I seen what I did...